# Prove that: $\overbrace{222...222}$(repeated $1980$ times), divisible by $1982$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that: $\overbrace{222...222}$(repeated $1980$ times), divisible by $1982$

Comment: Have you tried anything? What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: I tried with $(mod3)$ but I got nothing

Comment: What did you try with $\pmod 3$? It would be wise to include whatever efforts you have exerted within your question--it will be more favorably received and more likely to get quality answers.

Comment: not sure i understand question is it $2^{1980}$?

Comment: @miniparser Nope, the question is about the number with $1980$ digits, all of which are $2$s.

Answer (score 4):

$991$ is prime. Then, Fermat's theorem says that
$$10^{990}\equiv 1\pmod{991}$$

That is, the number with $990$ nines is a multiple of $991$.

This was the hard part. Can you continue?

Comment: actually, No, i didn't understand you

Comment: @Melano Note that $2 \cdot 990 = 1980$ and $2 \cdot 991 = 1982$.

Comment: @Melano Do you know Fermat's theorem?

Comment: Not much, If you complete you're answer I'll be appreciate it

Comment: fermats little theorem.  which has 2 forms

Comment: Without this theorem, you need some  other trick to show that a number with $990$ nines is a multiple of $991$. But, just assume this for granted.

Comment: after you complete you're answer I'll try to understand you solution

Comment: How about try and maybe look up Fermats Theorem

Comment: @Sean Looking up Fermat's little theorem would help the OP understand why $991$ divides $10^{990} - 1$, but we should consider that probably it isn't immediately clear how to use that piece of information for someone not used to this kind of reasoning.

Comment: @A.P. Yes I am aware of that but it just seems to me like the OP is trying to get a solution to a problem for free.